# Crystal Reports/ Visual Studio Dynamic Parameter Fields Problem

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have problem with Crystal reports with .NET in generating a report.  I have a report that gets data from a stored procedure ( sp_get_data(IN Claim_period)).  The IN parameter that goes to the stored procedure comes from a table in database.  It grows dynamically over period of time.  I need to add parameter claim_period to the report that is  (Select claim_period from claim table).  How can this be achieved.  I tried going through properties for Parameter fields but i am not able to find how.  I did select table CLAIM and the column under default values.  But it doesn't dynamically refreshes itself. Is there any way to this without coding dynamic parameters?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to do within crystal report.  It required coding.